# ruby inside slim strings

Tags: html, ruby, erb, slim-lang

In erb files I can do something like

```
<tr class="<%= cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even') %>">
```

How would this line look in a slim file?
Thx.

Comment: What's not clear about my question? Maybe somebody could at least comment what's wrong before doing a negative rating.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively:

```
tr[class=cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even')]
```

or

```
tr class=cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tr[class="#{cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even')}"]
```